# Is this transition probability matrix correct?

Tags: probability, distributions, markov-process, transition-matrix

A pensioner receives 2 (thousand dollars) at the beginning of each month. The amount of money he needs to spend during a month is independent of the amount he has and is equal to i with probability $P_i, i= 1,2,3,4,\sum_{i=1}^4 P_i =1.$
If the pensioner has more than 3 at the end of a month, he gives the amount greater than 3 to his son. If, after receiving his payment at the beginning of a month, the pensioner has a capital of 5, what is the probability that his capital is ever 1 or less at any time within the following four months?

**Solution:** To find the desired probability, we consider a Markov chain
with the state equal to the amount the pensioner has at the end of a
month.  Because the pensioner will give any end-of-month amount greater than 3 to his son, we need only consider the Markov chain with states 1, 2, 3 and transition probability matrix $Q=[Q_{i,j}]$
given by $$\begin{Vmatrix} P_2 & P_1 & 0 \\ P_3 + P_4 & P_2 & P_1 \\ P_4 & P_3 & P_1 + P_2\end{Vmatrix}$$

Is the above transition probability matrix computed by me correct? If wrong where and why it is wrong?

Author's computed transition probability matrix is as follows:
$$\begin{Vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ P_3 + P_4 & P_2 & P_1 \\ P_4 & P_3 & P_1 + P_2 \end{Vmatrix}$$

Is the above transition probability matrix correct? Why did  author show $Q_{(1,1)}= 1$ (absorbing state) and $Q_{(1,2)} , Q_{(1,3)}=0$ in the above matrix?

Would any member of 'Cross Validated' answer my question with correct explanation?

Comment: One of the characteristics of a transition matrix is that its rows sum to unity.  Unless $P_3=P_4=0,$ that obviously is not the case for the first row.

Comment: "what is the probability that his capital is ever 1 or less at any time within the following four months?" State 1 has to be absorbing, otherwise you could lose the information that the chain had ever been in state 1, and you would be unable to answer the question. If state 1 were not absorbing, you could only say whether the chain were in state 1 after $n$ steps, but you could not say if it had ever visited state 1 during steps $1...n-1$.

Comment: @jblood94, State 1 means pensioner's initial end-of-month capital was 1(thousand dollars). Now, 2 (thousand dollars) more will be added in beginning of next  month, so his capital will be 3(thousand dollars).  So, the amount of money, the pensioner needs to spend is $P_2$ so that his end of that month capital would be 1(thosand dollars). Likewise, as his capital is 3(thosand dollars) in the next month, pensioner would be in state 2, if he/she spends $P_1$.

Comment: But if the chain reaches state 1, it doesn't matter what happens in subsequent steps since we are only concerned with whether it was *ever* in state 1.

Comment: @jblood94, you answered my question.